# Using Jquery .next in a WordPress loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create an overlay effect with jquery inside of a WordPress loop to present the content of custom post type when clicking on its title.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <button href="#" class="popup-button">
        <? the_title(); ?>
    </button>

    <div class="popup-content"> 
      <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
    </div>
```

The popup-content is hidden in CSS.
and here is the JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('.popup-button', 'click', function(e) {
        $(this).next('.popup-content').dialog(); 
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working! please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have the arguments in the wrong order:

```
$(document).on('.popup-button', 'click', function(e) {
```

Should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popup-button', function(e) {
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: okay on is maybe bit faster, I just read somewhere not to use it which is wrong

Comment: You may be thinking of `.live()`

Comment: @abimelex Like I mentioned below your answer, you might actually need `on()` in case the content is not there yet on the initial page load.

Comment: Thanks but it still not working. I have Jquery.min.js linked in my head but no event fires whatsoever. I've got both the JS script and HTML in the same templates/parts file. The popup-content is outputed correctly but the hidden visibility is always on, I can't change it whether I use .show() or anything else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you need to tell the dialog to open:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "open" );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open

If not, make sure that you are including the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.popup-button', function(e) {
        $(this).next('.popup-content').css('visibility', 'visible'); 

    });
    $(document).on('click','.popup-content', function(e) {
      $('.popup-content').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});

</script> 


<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button href="#" class="popup-button">
        <? the_title(); ?>
    </button>

    <button class="popup-content"> 
        <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
    </button>
</div>
```